# Difference between the cardinalty of a metrizable topological group and its dense subgroup

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $(G,\mathcal T)$ be a metrizable topological group and $C$ be a dense countable subgroup of $G$. How large can be the cardinality of $G$? Can it have a larger cardinality than $|\Bbb R|$?

It seems that Jones' Lemma cannot be used because $C$ need not be discrete.

Comment: What does the group structure have to do with the question? Any separable metric space has a cardinality which is at most continuum.

Comment: A separable metric space (indeed a separable first-countable Hausdorff space) can have at most the cardinality of $|\mathbb R|.$ Each point in the space is the limit of a convergent sequence of points in the countable dense set, and the number of such sequences is at most $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb R|.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is any first-countable Hausdorff space and $C\subseteq X$ is a countable dense subset, then every element of $X$ is a limit of some sequence in $C$.  Since there are only $|C|^{|\mathbb{N}|}\leq|\mathbb{R}|$ different sequences in $C$ and each sequence has at most one limit, $X$ can have at most $|\mathbb{R}|$ different points.